# Deleting a Triple Pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I have a triple pointer to an Object in C++ and I need to free the entire thing after use.

```
MyClass *** foobar = new MyClass **[10000];
```

How do I write the delete statement for this.

Comment: @Tony: You should make it an answer. +1 nonetheless

Comment: @Tony: `delete foobar` is actually incorrect, should be `delete[] foobar`. Your other points are valid though.

Comment: @dalle: ouch... sorry.  I'll just delete my comment as it's too late to edit it.  Cheers.

Comment: @Tony: Noo! Your comment was very informative, except that tiny tiny thing.

Comment: @dalle: but it's been covered in answers now anyway I think... I voted up Max's as it goes through it in more detail than I had patience for today ;-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you allocate the pointers-to-pointers.  If you do:

```
int x;
int* p = &x;
int** pp = &p;
int*** ppp = &pp;
```

Then you don't have to `delete` anything.

On the other hand, if you do:

```
int* p = new int;
int** pp = &p;
int*** ppp = &pp;
```

Then you only have to `delete p`.  For:

```
// i.e., allocate 1000 ints, return a pointer, and then get the address of that pointer
int** pp = &(new int[1000]);
// Oh, and get the address of the int**
int*** ppp = &pp;
```

You have to `delete[] *pp` (i.e., dereference `pp` to get the original pointer to the array of `int`s, and then `delete[]` the array).

Comment: The last example will not compile.

Comment: I should have tested it.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How do you alloc it? Generally, if A is pointer to B, B is pointer to C and C is pointer to D (data), you need to free D, then C and B as the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you `new[]`, you will have to `delete[]`. It's that simple.

If you do it at several levels, you will have to `delete[]` in the reverse order of the `new[]`'s.

Answer (score 1):

If the only allocation that you have done is the one you show in the question, then you only need to do:

```
delete [] **foobar;
```

As that is the only memory that was actually acquired. If you have allocated memory to elements inside `foobar`, then you must clear them up in reverse order of creation.

Note that in most cases these types of structures can be simplified. For example, if the actual data to hold is a cube, you can allocate a single block of `1000*1000*1000` elements (that is a HUGE amount of them) and deallocate it with a single `delete []`. If you wrap the memory inside a class, then you can provide `operator()` that will map from three indices to the unique element in the sequential container. Take a look at the C++FAQ lite [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10).

Answer (score 0):

3D memory allocation

```
int ***allocate3D(int ***mat, int k, int l, int m)  {
  mat = (int***) malloc( sizeof(int)*k*l*m );

  for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    mat[i] = (int**) malloc ( sizeof(int)*l*m );

  for(int i=0; i<k; i++)  for(int j=0; j<l; j++) 
    mat[i][j] = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int)*m );

  return mat;
}
```

3D matrix deallocation:

```
void deAllocate3D(int ***mat, int k, int l, int m){
  //Delete in reverse order of allocation
  for(int i=0; i<k; i++) for(int j=0; j<l; j++) { free(mat[i][j]); mat[i][j] = NULL; }

  for(int i=0; i<k; i++) { free(mat[i]); mat[i] = NULL; }

  free(mat); mat = NULL;
}
```

Find the full source code [here](https://github.com/kevindra/Algorithm-Implementations/blob/master/memory_related/memDeallocate3DArray.cpp)